# Number of degree-$d$ representations of a perfect group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

It seems to be a standard result that the number of degree-1 representations of a group $G$ is equal to $[G : G']$ where $G'$ is the commutator subgroup (e.g. Lemma 6.2.7 in the 2012 textbook "Representation Theory of Finite Groups" by Steinberg).

A consequence is that a group is perfect (i.e. $G = G'$) iff the only degree-1 representation is the trivial one.

Is there any analogous theorem that bounds the number of degree-$(d > 1)$ representations of a perfect group, or gives some other characterization of them (that is unique to perfect groups)?

Comment: Are you asking about groups that have a unique irreducible representation of degree $d$ (for some fixed $d$)? Are you suggesting they are perfect, or assuming they are perfect?

Comment: I'm asking if there is any result that "characterizes" the degree-d representations of a perfect group in some way, e.g. that bounds the number of them. I will edit the question to make this more clear, thanks.

Comment: A small thing: there is a sequence of finite simple groups $G_n$ such that the number of irreducible representations of degree $d_n$ (depending on $n$) is at least $n$. So the number is not bounded independently of $d$.

Comment: Thanks -- is it easy to see that? And do you have any characterization of $d_n$?  Assuming it is a sequence of non-abelian simple groups then they are all perfect.

Comment: I added the SL2 groups. PSL2 works too, but is less uniform (sometimes you need to divide by another factor of 2).

Comment: Another result: for each $M$, there are only finitely many finite groups up to isomorphism with the property that for all $d$, the number of characters of degree $d$ is at most $M$. $M=1$ is classified. $M=2$ is fairly thoroughly studied and classified in several instances.

Comment: Thanks for all the information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G_p = \operatorname{SL}(2,p)$ for $p$ prime, $p \geq 5$. Then $G_p$ is a perfect group and has $\frac{p-1}{2}$ characters of degree $p-1$.

Taking $p$ to be the first prime greater than or equal to $2n+1$, we get that $G_p$ has more than $n$ characters of degree $p-1$.

Most groups of Lie type have high multiplicity character degrees (multiplicity above some multiple of $q^r$ where $r$ is the twisted lie rank and $q$ is the smaller of the possibilities for $q$, so that $q^t$ is the field size with $t$ the degree of the twist).

I didn't check alternating groups, but they probably work as well.